# Bash script creates separate files with same content

Tags: bash

I have 3 sets of files each located in different folders, therefore I cannot cd into a folder or use a for loop extension line in my bash script. 
My last script in my bash is just written as follows:

```
  python test.py
```

In my test.py script:

```
    for file in os.listdir(/path to folder1):
        with open((/path to folder4+file+'.txt')), 'w') as w:
             w.write #according to calculations calculated earlier in test.py from folder1
             w.write #according to calculations calculated earlier in test.py from folder2
             w.write #according to calculations calculated earlier in test.py from folder3
```

It does this correctly when I go through my first PDB file (output: PDB1.txt), but when it runs through the second one I get PDB2.txt but it contains the content of PDB1.txt. Is this a problem, that I am somehow hard-coding even though I say to loop over my files in those folders in the script?

Comment: @sjaustirni hope this clarifies, there are a lot of scripts involved but this is where my problem stems from

Comment: `I cannot cd into a folder or use a for loop extension line in my bash script`, well, you can always `find`. Why do i see bash in your post and tag and i see python in your source. Is it python or bash?

Comment: @KamilCuk I just run the python script in that manner in my bash script. But I actually managed to fix it by storing my calculations in a list then iterating through them in a for loop in my test.py script. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:instead of using return, I append the answers to a list and then I loop over the answers in my list

```
   def funtion1():
        list1 = []
        (do calculations)
        return list1()

   def main_function():   
        f1 = function1()
        for file in os.listdir(/path to folder1):
            with open((/path to folder4+file+'.txt')), 'w') as w:
                 for i in f1:
                      w.write(f1[i]) #according to calculations calculated earlier in test.py from folder1
```

So now, instead of just returning the same calculation when I iterate over the list that contains multiple calculations from different files it correctly reads each.